# How to create virtual machine using WMIC on hyper-v with python script or any command?

Tags: python, linux, centos6, hyper-v, wmic

I am new to Hyper-v,WMI and using WMIC i need to create a VM(virtual machine). Can anybody help me through a sample code or script to refer? Preferred script language is Python and I am using CentOS 6 to run wmic. And is there any way to create VM via wmic commands? I have gone through many scripts and code snippets but they were all in powershell and I dont want to use powershell.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many scripts in C# to do the same work

if you dont want to use powershell scripts you can choose the best method to run a powershell command for each thing and run the powershell command from python script

i did the same in C# with Process Class

Comment: But how to achieve this in centos 6?

Comment: I never used centos I just answered you because you cant use powershell Got a doubt is centos can run wmi or you can install hyper v on Centos ?

Comment: thats what my question was how can I manage hyper-v from my centos machine remotely.